Motor locks when the duty cycle of the half bridge PMDC drive circuit is 0 percent
I am designed a PMDC motor driver. The schmatic diagram is the half bridge circuit I use for unipolar drive. I am controlling the driver circuit with PWM signals from a microcontroller on the PCB. In design I forget important parameter which is freewheel of motor. When the duty cycle and is set to "0," the motor terminals are shorted, braking the motor. That is undesired behaviour in my design. I should able to get coasting (freewheeling) at "0" dutycycle. What should I implement or what can I add to my controller? What will be  if I set to float MOT+ terminal at "0" duty?


You'd have to turn off both FETs, look for a disable pin on your driver chip. Or add information about the driver to the question.
